# Clouse vs Non-Closure Function + `this`?

Tags: javascript, closures

Just trying to understand closure vs non-clousure functions. So when I run the following...

```
function outer()
{
     var i = 0;
     i++;
     
     console.log( i );

}

outer(); // prints 1
outer(); // prints 1
outer(); // prints 1
```

But when I run the following ...

```
function outer()
{
         var i = 0;

         function inner()
         {
                  i++;
                  console.log( i );
             }

         return inner;
}

var closure = outer();
closure(); // prints 1
closure(); // prints 2
closure(); // prints 3
```

That's fine. I understand the above. However, when I try to run the following ...

```
function outer()
{
     var i = 0;
     i++;
     
     console.log( i );

}

var closure = outer();
closure(); // prints 1
closure(); // prints 2
closure(); // prints 3
```

I get an error because unlike in the closure, the function is not being returned here. So, I modified it to the following ...

```
function outer()
{
     var i = 0;
     i++;
     
     console.log( i );

    return this;
}

var closure = outer();
closure(); // prints 1
closure(); // prints 2
closure(); // prints 3
```

I still get an error, only to find out that `this` in this context does not refer to the parent function... Rather it refers to the global object. No wonder it gave an error. But what can I replace `this` with, to refer to the `outer()` function?

Secondly, even then... Will I be able to simulate the closure? I reckon not... But why?

Comment: The `this` keyword rarely ever refers to a function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but maybe `return function inner() { console.log(i); };` or `return outer;`?

Comment: Well, are you returning *a function* from your function? Only in one case. In the others `closure` is not a function and hence can’t be called.

Comment: In a nutshell, `this` refers to the object that the function is a part of. Not to the function itself.

Comment: *”Secondly, even then... Will I be able to simulate the closure?”* - No, because at best you’d be replicating your first case. You can’t simulate a closure without writing a closure.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for that.... And the rest of you too. Much apprecaited.

Comment: This post could clarify some of your doubts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This code `var closure = outer()` will execute the outer function and will assign the result to `closure`. But since there is nothing returned from `outer` `closure()` will not work as it expects a function. In this case you can try by removing `()` from outer.

Also in this case returning `this` is same as returning nothing. Inside this function `this` revers to window object so `closure()` is becoming `this()`

```js
function outer() {
  var i = 0;
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  return this;
}

var closure = outer;
console.log(closure());
closure();
closure();
```

```css
I get an error because unlike in the closure,
the function is not being returned here. So,
I modified it to the following ...
```